# Query Selector is Null when I use insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm using insertAdjacentHtml to create a div with a button right after the opening body tag of the page.

```
<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            var code = '<div class="overlay"><button class="overlay-close"></button></div>';
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', code);
        }, false);</script>
```

But I get an error with the querySelector on my closeBttn.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

```
<script>
        (function() {
            var overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
                closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
                /* irrelevent other code here */
        })();
</script>
```

Clearly it looks like I have the overlay button and overlay div present, but it still not working. It works fine without using insertAdjacentHTML, but once I wrapped my code in this function, I get the error, so I'm thinking there's something going on here when I use this function to create my div.

Can anyone help to debug or give a work around?

Comment: When is the second piece of code being run? Your error would indicate to me that the code is being run *before* DOMContentLoaded, so no div.overlay exists in the body.

Comment: @LiamEgan Thanks you were right. It worked after adding this: (document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
   var overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),

Answer (score 0):

The code was loading before DomContentLoaded so I changed my code to the following:

```
<script>
        (document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function() {
            var overlay = document.querySelector( 'div.overlay' ),
                closeBttn = overlay.querySelector( 'button.overlay-close' );
                /* irrelevent other code here */
        }));
</script>
```